# 12 May, Tue getting java.text.parse exception

Tags: java

i'm using

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, EEE");
```

for parsing

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, EEE");
Date deptDate = formatter.parse("12 May, Tue")
```

getting `java.text.parse` exp

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `May` is a correct month name in your locale? Because it is in English:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Yes, it is there. and also tried with both (Local.ENGLISH and without Local)

Comment: @Mukesh You did? Because your code is working for me if I add the locale.

Comment: Thanks Marvin and Tom, it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must Throw the Exception from your method `ParseException`

This code works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, EEE");
        Date deptDate = formatter.parse("12 May, Tue");
        System.out.println(deptDate);
    }
```

Comment: well this is not working for me, and i have try catch in my function so i guess these is no need for throws ParseException

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and its working :)

```
package test;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, EEE");
    Date deptDate;
    try {
        deptDate = formatter.parse("12 May, Tue");
        System.out.println(deptDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```